# CakePHP Setting recursive for select joins

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I create a search on models like this:

```
$options = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'CompletedSurvey.' . $this->CompletedSurvey->primaryKey => $id
    ),
    'recursive' => 5
);
$survey = $this->CompletedSurvey->find('first', $options);
```

The way I have my models set up, this will return five models (do to their various joins) each recursed up to 5 times (if available). The problem is that I only want one of these models to be recursed X5.  The others don't need to be.

Is there a way to tell the find function which tables to recurse and at what level to recurse them to?  So, telling cake which models to recurse and at what level for each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is not exactly recursive, but the only way to access deep relations and avoid to use recursive on a main model is to use containable behavior:

```
$options = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'CompletedSurvey.' . $this->CompletedSurvey->primaryKey => $id
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'SomeModel.SomeOtherModel.AnotherModel.AnotherModel'
    ) 
);

$survey = $this->CompletedSurvey->find('first', $options);
```

And don't forget to set containable behavior for CompletedSurvey model!

```
class CompletedSurvey extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

Comment: The [**recursive option**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containablebehavior-options) of the containable behavior is a boolean, and it's enabled by default!

Answer (score 2):

Please read the CakePHP cookbook regarding the recursive property on models, as it does not work the way you are thinking.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive

What you're looking for is the containable behavior, where you can specify exactly which models to return.  Please see the cookbook on how to use containable.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html